# Angularjs $on $routeChangeSuccess error on first load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have scoured the internet for the past few days trying to figure out how to fix this problem. I'm not sure if I'm just not wording the question right or it's a simple solution that I just can't seem to see.

My issue is that in my $routeProvider I have added a property called 'access' in each route to determine if a user has to be logged in or not to view a page using a variable called 'isFree' that is set to true or false.

Example:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
  controller: 'homeController',
  templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
  access: { isFree: true }
});
```

Then I have a block of code in a .run function that watches for route changes and checks if the page requires the user to be signed in and if they are already signed in. If the pages 'isFree' is set to true then it should let the page load, otherwise it checks to see if the user is signed in, and if not it redirects back to the home page.

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($root, $location) {
$root.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(scope, curRoute, prevRoute) {
   if (!curRoute.access.isFree && !loggedIn) {
     $location.path('/');
   }
});
```

The issue I am having is not that this code does not work. The problem is that when you first load to the home page (which isFree is set to true) the console gives an error that 'isFree' is not defined. The homepage itself still loads and the site works properly after that first error. However, I do not want that error to pop up in the first place. As far as I can figure out when I link directly to the homepage for the first time it try's to check the isFree property before it's even been loaded, but I have yet to solve my problem. If anyone knows what I can do to fix this small issue it would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a $routeProvider.otherwise definition?

Comment: Yes, but it was also giving me the 'isFree' is not defined error. The issue is solved now. Mather Berg's solution worked.

Comment: Did you add 'access: { isFree: true }' to the otherwise definition? My guess is that the otherwise defintion is hit first, and your code in $routeChangeStart checks access.isFree which is missing.

Comment: I reverted and tested to see if your suggestion would work, but even after I added 'access: { isFree: true }' to .otherwise I still got the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your curRoute.access is not defined, so try this as your if statement instead:

```
if ((!curRoute.access || !curRoute.access.isFree) && !loggedIn) {
    $location.path('/');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be something simple, but to be honest I got to that point where my brain wasn't cooperating with me.